# How do I catch an NPE and send custom error to Publisher in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I am doing an rxified version of what is shown here: (https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-amqp-client/java/#_creating_a_receiver).

Basically, the code below gets messages whenever they are received on a connection. Behind the scenes I am simulating a broken connection by stopping the message broker service. This results in the AMQP code throwing an NPE. I would like to catch the NPE and send a better error to the subscriber.

When the NPE occurs I can't seem to capture the error, so I'm unsure how to accomplish this.

```
public Publisher<Object> receiveAmqpMessages(AmqpConnection connection, String address) {
  return connection
   .rxCreateReceiver(address)
   .flatMapPublisher(receiver ->
     receiver.toObservable()
       .doFinally(receiver::rxClose)
       .onErrorReturn(e-> {
          System.out.println("I never see this message");
          return null;
       }.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
   );
}
```

I tried wrapping it in a try/catch like so but it doesn't go into the catch block

```
public Publisher<Object> receiveAmqpMessages(AmqpConnection connection, String address) {
  try {
    // same code shown above
  } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.out.println("I never see this message either");
    return Observable.error(new Exception("foo")).toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
  }
}
```

FWIW the console looks like this (Note - The console never outputs anything that references my own class file):

```
SEVERE: Unhandled Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at io.vertx.ampq.impl.AmqpConnectionImpl.lambda$createReceiver$8(Line 251)
...
```

If you open their AmqpConnectionImpl and go to that line of code you see

```
ProtonReceiver receiver = connection.get().createReceiver(address,opts)
```

which causes the NPE since connection.get() is null

Comment: Do you want to use `onErrorReturn()` instead?

Comment: No, because I don't have a valid object to send back to them

Comment: What do you mean by "better error" then? Clearly you have something you want to do or return instead when you have caught the exception.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the example output/values you get from `someThirdPartyLib.someThirdPartyCall()` and the result you from these values. Also explain what you are trying to do with `flatMapPublisher()` in that location.

Comment: ok, I added a lot more detail. hopefully enough to go off of :)

Comment: I think the NPE might be thrown not inside your rx pipeline, but by the code that's building the pipeline. Specifically in the call:
`.rxCreateReceiver(address)`

Comment: Trogdor, that is correct. I am trying to capture it and return something better.